# How to map a table in application-memory to queries

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

This issue has me bugging, and I cant find it on google or anything.

Im using MySQL/MariaSQL for this problem.

My problem is not related products/categories, but I will use the analogy.

Suppose you have a list of records (products), with lots of information (columns) about each (including eg. the amount of units currently in the warehouse for each product). Suppose you also categorize your records.

A simple INNER JOIN with SUM and GROUP will give you the units in the warehouse per category:

```
CREATE TABLE product  ( product_id BIGINT , units_in_warehouse BIGINT );
CREATE TABLE category ( category_id BIGINT , product_id BIGINT );

INSERT INTO product  VALUES (1,5),(2,1),(3,8),(4,9),(5,10),(6,2),(7,9),(8,12),(9,3);
INSERT INTO category VALUES (1,8),(1,7),(1,7),(2,6),(2,2),(2,6),(2,5),(2,4),(2,5),(3,9),(3,3),(3,1),(4,4),(4,2),(4,8),(5,2),(5,1),(5,3),(5,9),(5,8),(5,1);

SELECT category_id, SUM( units_in_warehouse ) AS category_units_in_warehouse
FROM product 
INNER JOIN category 
ON product.product_id = category.product_id 
GROUP BY category_id;

DROP TABLE product;
DROP TABLE category;
```

My problem is what if your category table is completely different each application processing time, based on criteria that only your application knows (Eg. The DB does not store tables/fields to reconstruct a feasible categorizing list)? Essentially, the category table is stored on the Application side, and it is not feasible (due to application context) to store it in the DB?

1. I could use **temporary tables**. But in my problem, the product and category quantity is quite large (+-10K records), and I need about 10 temporary tables for different grouping uses. It does not occur to me as a sensible solution to create 10 temporary tables, execute 10K-large Insert clauses, and do it again and again for each application request.
2. I was hoping to define the tables as **static-defined lists** in queries, a bit like IN () does, though the list is reused at the GROUP clause (and hence you cant use IN () )

Like:

```
SELECT category_id, SUM( units_in_warehouse ) AS category_units_in_warehouse
FROM product 
INNER JOIN (
 /* Badly written SQL here */
 SELECT category_id , product_id 
 VALUES (1,8),(1,7),(1,7),(2,6),(2,2),(2,6),(2,5),(2,4),(2,5),(3,9),(3,3),(3,1),(4,4),(4,2),(4,8),(5,2),(5,1),(5,3),(5,9),(5,8),(5,1)
 /* /Badly written SQL here */
) category 
ON product.product_id = category.product_id 
GROUP BY category_id;
```

...But I have not come across any SQL syntax/word/method to be able to do this.

Anyone any suggestions? How would you efficiently map a table in application-memory to the DB for queries?

Comment: ...Maybe a related article: https://modern-sql.com/use-case/select-without-from

Comment: Is a product in only one category?  Or do you have a many:many relationship?

Comment: @Rick: Many to many.

Answer (score 0):

Though, I am not sure if it is the most efficient way but you can try the following:

```
SELECT category_id, SUM( units_in_warehouse ) AS category_units_in_warehouse
FROM product 
INNER JOIN (
 SELECT 1 as category_id , 8 as product_id 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1,7
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 1,7
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2,6
) category 
ON product.product_id = category.product_id 
GROUP BY category_id;
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. Are you exclaiming at the amount of coding that you have to do? :)

Comment: I was referring at the hope that MySQL would provide a better solution than this, at the size of the query, and indeed how inefficient UNION ALL may run. 30chars per row makes under 0.5MB for 10K rows.

Answer (score 0):

If product:category is many:many, there needs to be a third table to show the many:many mapping.  For clarity, it should be called something like `product_category` (not simply `category`).

Then, you are likely to need to `JOIN` all 3 tables to bring up information about products and their categories.

Efficiency considerations for the mapping table are given here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Comment: You are suggesting to store categorizing data in the DB, but my problem/the question mentions 'your category table is completely different each application processing time, based on criteria that only your application knows', hence this doesn't solve it.